# Adding values from a file to an array until a certain character

Tags: c

I am working on a program that uses file redirection to read in a file, read one character per line until I reach a '0', store the characters in an array , and sort that array (from largest to smallest). Anyway, I really only need help with reading the characters until the zero shows up. Below is the text file that I am reading in:

```
f
k
s
j
p
a
v
r
t
u
h
m
g
e
b
y
n
z
w
l
i
x
q
c
o
d
0
```

Below is the code I have so far:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    char array[100];

    while(fscanf(stdin, "%c", &array[i]) && array[i]!='0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    int N = (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("%c", array[i]);
    }

return(0);
}
```

When I run this program, it prints out every line of the file, including the zero. It also prints out some really weird characters after the zero (using gcc compiler). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider `fgetc` https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc. Also it will return `EOF`, a special value that isn't a character, for end of file. So you don't need that 0 at the end

Comment: mind the newlines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `i` to keep track of how many items you've read, but then you overwrite the value of `i` in your loop and print out all 100 elements, whether you stored something there or not.

Use different variable for counting the element than you do for looping, and use the count as your loop limit.

```
int count=0;
char array[100];

while(fscanf(stdin, "%c", &array[count]) && array[count]!='0')
{
    count++;
}

for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    printf("%c", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I should have realized this before. It was nothing more than a stupid oversight. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `N` to the value of `i`, currently it will always be 100

Answer (score 0):

fscanf needs to skip the separator (enter or space), else it will be incorporated into your list. Adding a space fixes that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sort (const void *a,const void *b)
{
    return ((int)*((unsigned char *)a)) - ((int)*((unsigned char *)b));
}

int main (void)
{
    unsigned char array[100],i=0;
    while (fscanf(stdin," %c", &array[i]) && array[i] != '0')
        i++;
    qsort (array,i,1,sort);
    while (i)
        printf ("%c\n", array[--i]);
}
```

It may seem this program sorts the wrong way around but the printing loop also happens to print in reverse, so that solves it neatly. As the array is unsigned char, the sort routine casts this to `int` to prevent possible overflow.